# Missing horizontal or vertical lines when drawing backwards TikZ grids

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids

Look at next code, when I want to draw a grid from right to left or top to bottom, vertical or horizontal lines are not drawn, even with `xstep=-1` or `ystep=-1` (as it's suggested in Jake's answer in [Grid missing horizontal lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55540/1952)).

What am I missing? I'm using TikZ's CVS version.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\arrow}[2]{\draw[->,blue,thick,shorten <=5mm, shorten >=5mm] #1 -- #2 ;}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (-2,-2) grid (2,2); 
\draw[red,fill] (0,0) circle (1mm) node[below right] {(0,0)};
\node[anchor=south,align=center] at (0,2){(-2,-2) to (2,2)};
\arrow{(-2,-2)}{(2,2)}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (-2,2) grid[ystep=-1] (2,-2);
\arrow{(-2,2)}{(2,-2)}
\draw[red,fill] (0,0) circle (1mm) node[above right] {(0,0)};
\node[anchor=south,align=center] at (0,2){(-2,2) to (2,-2)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (2,-2) grid[xstep=-1] (-2,2);
\arrow{(2,-2)}{(-2,2)}
\draw[red,fill] (0,0) circle (1mm) node[above right] {(0,0)};
\node[anchor=south,align=center] at (0,2){(2,-2) to (-2,2)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (2,2) grid[xstep=-1,ystep=-1] (-2,-2);
\arrow{(2,2)}{(-2,-2)}
\draw[red,fill] (0,0) circle (1mm) node[below right] {(0,0)};
\node[anchor=south,align=center] at (0,2){(2,2) to (-2,-2)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think what is happening here is that when you saying

    `\draw[help lines] (-2,2) grid[ystep=-1] (2,-2)`

sets the y grid line to start at `y=2`.  The second coordinate specifies the end point, so the grid is to end at `y=-2`. So taking the starting value of `y=2`,  adding  the value of `ystep` yields `y=1`, which is already greater then the end value of `y=-2`, so the `y` grid is considered done.

Similar explanations apply to the other two examples.

Comment: I guess the ending test should really take into account if the y-step is negative that the test should be reversed to be less than, or not allow a negative y-step.

Comment: @PeterGrill From your comments I understand this is a 'bug' in TikZ. Isn't it?

Comment: If the documentation say that that should have worked then it is probably a bug. Otherwise, it is just not the way things work and grids are drawn from bottom left to top right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **EDIT** : This issue is now fixed in the current development version (CVS) of TikZ/PGF. The fix is not what is proposed below but from Till Tantau's comment:
>
> > Fixed in CVS. However, negative increments are (still) not allowed. Instead, the two parameters of the pgfpathgrid command are now considered as two corners of a rectangle rather than as explicitly the lower left and upper right corner. This fixes the problem in the way people expect.

---

If I'm not mistaken somewhere, I've patched the `\pgfpathgrid` command found in `pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex` file. But please let me know if it fails in any other cases that I might have skipped.

With this you don't need to use negative step sizes since it will increment accordingly.

In a nutshell, I've checked if the start point is larger than the finish point and then multiply a few inequalities with `-1` with `\c@pgf@counta` being the conditional variable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter


\def\pgfpathgrid{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\pgf@pathgrid}{\pgf@pathgrid[]}}
\def\pgf@pathgrid[#1]#2#3{%
  \pgfset{#1}%
  \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xc{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/stepx}}%
  \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@yc{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/stepy}}%
  \pgf@process{#3}%
  \pgf@xb=\pgf@x%
  \pgf@yb=\pgf@y%
  \pgf@process{#2}%
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@x\relax%
  \pgf@ya=\pgf@y\relax%
  {%
    % compute bounding box
    % first corner
    \pgf@x=\pgf@xb%
    \pgf@y=\pgf@yb%
    \pgf@pos@transform{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}%
    \pgf@protocolsizes{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}%
    % second corner
    \pgf@x=\pgf@xb%
    \pgf@y=\pgf@ya%
    \pgf@pos@transform{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}%
    \pgf@protocolsizes{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}%
    % third corner
    \pgf@x=\pgf@xa%
    \pgf@y=\pgf@yb%
    \pgf@pos@transform{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}%
    \pgf@protocolsizes{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}%
    % fourth corner
    \pgf@x=\pgf@xa%
    \pgf@y=\pgf@ya%
    \pgf@pos@transform{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}%
    \pgf@protocolsizes{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}%
  }%
  \c@pgf@counta=\pgf@y\relax% Truncate the start y coordinate to integer
  \c@pgf@countb=\pgf@yc\relax% Truncate the step size to integer
  \divide\c@pgf@counta by\c@pgf@countb\relax% Truncate the ratio
  \pgf@y=\c@pgf@counta\pgf@yc\relax% % Find the closest integer-multiple of step size to the start
    \ifdim\pgf@ya>\pgf@yb% If the start point is larger than finish 
        \c@pgf@counta=-1\relax
    \else % If everything is fine
        \c@pgf@counta=1\relax
    \fi
  \ifdim\the\c@pgf@counta\pgf@y<\the\c@pgf@counta\pgf@ya% If for some reason it goes too far
    \advance\pgf@y by\the\c@pgf@counta\pgf@yc% take back one step size
  \fi%
  \loop% horizontal lines
    {%
      \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
      \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
      \pgf@pos@transform{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}
      \pgfsyssoftpath@moveto{\the\pgf@xa}{\the\pgf@ya}%
      \pgf@xa=\pgf@xb%
      \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
      \pgf@pos@transform{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}
      \pgfsyssoftpath@lineto{\the\pgf@xa}{\the\pgf@ya}%
    }%
    \advance\pgf@y by\the\c@pgf@counta\pgf@yc% Increment in the - or + direction
  \ifdim\the\c@pgf@counta\pgf@y<\the\c@pgf@counta\pgf@yb% Also compare with the correct sign.
  \repeat%
  \advance\pgf@y by 0.01\dimexpr0pt-(1pt)*\c@pgf@counta\relax%
  \ifdim\the\c@pgf@counta\pgf@y<\the\c@pgf@counta\pgf@yb
    {%
      \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
      \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
      \pgf@pos@transform{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}
      \pgfsyssoftpath@moveto{\the\pgf@xa}{\the\pgf@ya}%
      \pgf@xa=\pgf@xb%
      \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
      \pgf@pos@transform{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}
      \pgfsyssoftpath@lineto{\the\pgf@xa}{\the\pgf@ya}%
    }%
  \fi%
  \c@pgf@counta=\pgf@x\relax%
  \c@pgf@countb=\pgf@xc\relax%
  \divide\c@pgf@counta by\c@pgf@countb\relax%
  \pgf@x=\c@pgf@counta\pgf@xc\relax%
    \ifdim\pgf@xa>\pgf@xb% If the start point is larger than finish 
      \c@pgf@counta=-1\relax
    \else % If everything is fine
      \c@pgf@counta=1\relax
    \fi
  \ifdim\the\c@pgf@counta\pgf@x<\the\c@pgf@counta\pgf@xa%
    \advance\pgf@x by\the\c@pgf@counta\pgf@xc%
  \fi%
  \loop% vertical lines
    {%
      \pgf@xc=\pgf@x%
      \pgf@yc=\pgf@ya%
      \pgf@pos@transform{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}
      \pgfsyssoftpath@moveto{\the\pgf@xc}{\the\pgf@yc}%
      \pgf@xc=\pgf@x%
      \pgf@yc=\pgf@yb%
      \pgf@pos@transform{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}
      \pgfsyssoftpath@lineto{\the\pgf@xc}{\the\pgf@yc}%
    }%
    \advance\pgf@x by\the\c@pgf@counta\pgf@xc% Increment in the - or + direction
  \ifdim\the\c@pgf@counta\pgf@x<\the\c@pgf@counta\pgf@xb% Also compare with the correct sign.
  \repeat%
  \advance\pgf@x by 0.01\dimexpr0pt-(1pt)*\c@pgf@counta\relax%
  \ifdim\the\c@pgf@counta\pgf@x<\the\c@pgf@counta\pgf@xb%
    {%
      \pgf@xc=\pgf@x%
      \pgf@yc=\pgf@ya%
      \pgf@pos@transform{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}
      \pgfsyssoftpath@moveto{\the\pgf@xc}{\the\pgf@yc}%
      \pgf@xc=\pgf@x%
      \pgf@yc=\pgf@yb%
      \pgf@pos@transform{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}
      \pgfsyssoftpath@lineto{\the\pgf@xc}{\the\pgf@yc}%
    }%
  \fi%
}


\makeatother

\newcommand{\arrow}[2]{\draw[->,blue,thick,shorten <=5mm, shorten >=5mm] #1 -- #2 ;}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (-2,-2) grid (2,2); 
\draw[red,fill] (0,0) circle (1mm) node[below right] {(0,0)};
\node[anchor=south,align=center] at (0,2){(-2,-2) to (2,2)};
\arrow{(-2,-2)}{(2,2)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (-2,2) grid[ystep=0.33] (2,-2);
\arrow{(-2,2)}{(2,-2)}
\draw[red,fill] (0,0) circle (1mm) node[above right] {(0,0)};
\node[anchor=south,align=center] at (0,2){(-2,2) to (2,-2)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (2,-2) grid[xstep=0.66] (-2,2);
\arrow{(2,-2)}{(-2,2)}
\draw[red,fill] (0,0) circle (1mm) node[above right] {(0,0)};
\node[anchor=south,align=center] at (0,2){(2,-2) to (-2,2)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (2,2) grid[xstep=0.5,ystep=0.5] (-2,-2);
\arrow{(2,2)}{(-2,-2)}
\draw[red,fill] (0,0) circle (1mm) node[below right] {(0,0)};
\node[anchor=south,align=center] at (0,2){(2,2) to (-2,-2)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. First tests worked but if I find any problem I'll let you know. I think you should consider to submit the patch to [`TikZ` maintainers](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/).

Comment: @Ignasi Done :) https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3585110&group_id=142562&atid=752794