# TikZ change coordinate system so Y points downwards

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

How can I change the default coordinate system of TikZ, so the Y coordinates go downwards, instead of upwards. This is because in the picture I'm trying to draw it is more natural to reference points this way.

I was trying to use negative values in the declaration, but some drawing commands don't really like it, like the `grid`, where horizontal lines simply don't get drawn this way:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=-1cm]
\draw (0, 0) grid (7, 7);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Result:

[image: non-working grids]

Comment: See this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79161/missing-horizontal-or-vertical-lines-when-drawing-backwards-tikz-grids and also the linked http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55540/grid-missing-horizontal-lines

Comment: @percusse: there might be other problems with negative values (although grid was the first problem I encountered), and those links only deal with the grids. The `yscale=1` however seems to have no bad side effects (at least for the cases I need)

Comment: Any other command is OK with `y=-1cm` but the `grid` :) So it's an unlucky start I would say :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use `yscale=-1`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1]
\draw (0, 0) grid (7, 7);
\node at (7,7) {A};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]