# Horizontal grid lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids

I have a problem with horizontal grid lines in a graph (I am trying to overlay a 1cm x 1cm grid to my pages, and stumbled upon this in the process):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}   
\tikz[]{%
    \draw [help lines,red,ystep=1cm,xstep=1cm] (0,0) node{A} grid +(3cm, -3cm) node{B};
        }   
\tikz[]{%
    \draw [help lines,blue,ystep=1cm,xstep=1cm] (0,0) node{A} grid +(3cm, 3cm) node{B};
        }  
\tikz[]{%
    \draw [help lines,green,ystep=-1cm,xstep=1cm] (0,0) node{A} grid +(3cm, -3cm) node{B};
        }
\end{document}
```

with this result:

[image: three strange grids]

Notice that the green grid has a negative ystep as suggested in [Grid missing horizontal lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55540/grid-missing-horizontal-lines), but still I have no lines.

So I decided that I probably do not understand how grids are generated; can someone shed some light here?

Comment: Do you really get this image from your MWE? I am getting errors and another output. Please check!

Comment: @LaRiFaRi re-checked by cutting and pasting in a new file. I have TeXlive 2013 on an Ubuntu 14.04.2 desktop. No errors. Puzzled.

Comment: @Rmano: You might want to upgrade your TikZ package to 3.0. On Overleaf, the third image gives an error, but the first two yield the same (correct) result: https://www.overleaf.com/2526302tzgdwx#/6615464/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please update your Ti*k*Z version. You should not use negative steps if your vectors are not defined in negative directions. Just do like the following in order to span the grid:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope} % south west to north east
        \draw [help lines,red,ystep=1cm,xstep=1cm] (0,0) node{A} grid +(3,3) node{B};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope} % north west to south east
        \draw [help lines,blue,ystep=1cm,xstep=1cm] (4,3) node{A} grid +(3,-3) node{B};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope} % north east to south west
        \draw [help lines,green,ystep=1cm,xstep=1cm] (11,3) node{A} grid +(-3,-3) node{B};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope} % south east to north west
        \draw [help lines,ystep=1cm,xstep=1cm] (15,0) node{A} grid +(-3,+3) node{B};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Althoug I think that this is the correct answer --- with my current tikz using ` \draw [help lines,green,ystep=1cm,xstep=1cm] (0, -3cm)  grid (3cm, 0) (0, 0) node {A} (3cm, -3cm) node {B};` --- IOW, specifying always `(bottom left corner) grid (upper right corner). Thanks.